# как сгенеровать уникальный код длиной n символов из строки?Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

к примеру есть 

$string = 'hello@mail.com'; mails постоянно будут разные

есть идея 

$generated = Hash::make($string)
//на выходе
//$2y$10$m.Fp9teOaXyR18.z1ajCMe8..wTY8f7l2qDCThu87ugP/LRCIo1eS

//Если эту строку обрезать то будет ли она уникальной? 
//Или как лучше сделать? 
//Нужно чтобы был уникальный код к примеру 8 символов
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [Hash::make()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing) использует [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) функцию, которая не гарантирует уникальность.

Для генерации рандомной строки фиксированной длины можете использовать функцию [random_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) и проверяйте ее уникальность.

Comment: спасибо, а проверить на уникальность это сделать запрос в DB?

$bytes = random_bytes(4);
 $code = bin2hex($bytes)

if(Url::where('code', $code)->first()){
   //заново генерировать?
}

Comment: @code7 судя по вашему комменту, у вас [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/287469). Если что, в Ларе есть встроенные способы восстановления пароля - просто предполагаю, что вы делаете что-то такое. Уточните в вопросе какую проблему решаете.

Comment: @code7 да, как вариант